# Webpack cannot reslove path

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to build my project using webpack, but it is throwing a error **Can't resolve './src/routes/index' in '/var/www/new_system/pwa_api**

below is my webpack.development.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    entry: 'app.ts',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    resolve: {
      modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'],
      alias: {
        'Config': path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/development.json')
      }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/devBuild/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

i am using nodejs express framework, with typescript.

project structure >>
[image]